# Python Script PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied when attempting to run

Tags: python, windows, terminal

I tried to create a Python script that compresses a .vtf file again

```
import subprocess

def compress_vtf(input_path, output_path, compression_format="dxt1"):
    try:
        # Construct the vtfcmd.exe command
        command = [
            '"C:/Program Files/Nem\'s Tools/VTFEdit/vtfcmd.exe"',
            '-file', input_path,
            '-output', output_path,
            '-format', compression_format
        ]

        # Run the command
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)

        print(f"Compression successful. Output file saved to {output_path}")

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

# Example usage
input_file = "G:/box_sq_1.vtf"
output_file = "G:/output_box_sq_1.vtf"
compression_format = "dxt1"  # Change this to "dxt5" or other supported formats

compress_vtf(input_file, output_file, compression_format)
```

I keep getting this error, input_file WAS on the C Drive (actually C:/Users/Me/Desktop to the file but I moved it to G (an external hard drive) to see if it was the C drive permission issues.

> Exception has occurred: PermissionError
> [WinError 5] Access is denied
> File "G:\vtfthing\vtfthing.py", line 14, in compress_vtf
> subprocess.run(command, check=True)
> File "G:\vtfthing\vtfthing.py", line 26, in 
> compress_vtf(input_file, output_file, compression_format)
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

I've checked permissions. I've run Visual Studio Code as an administrator, I even tried running it in CMD as admin (right click run as administrator) and running the .py script from there but it didnt work sadly.

Can't find anything online relating to this specifically.